# KsqlDB HOPPING window retention doesn't work

Tags: ksqldb

I am using ksqlDB version 0.14.0-rc732.

Declared a query :

```
CREATE TABLE LIVE_TRAFFIC AS
select
       devicemac,
       sum(traffic -> bytesIn) AS bytes_in,
       sum(traffic -> bytesOut) AS bytes_out
from FLAT_TRAFFIC
    WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 1 MINUTES, ADVANCE BY 1 MINUTES, RETENTION 15 MINUTES, GRACE PERIOD 1 MINUTES)
GROUP by  devicemac;
```

But the 15 min defined retention doesn't work.
Rows are being added to the table.